# Get Reactor Subscriber Context in doOnSubscribe, doOnSuccess and doOnError

Tags: spring-boot, project-reactor

I'm trying to implement the Reactor Subscriber Context (http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context) so I can pass values from my SLF4J MDC into a Flux where I then can use the values for logging.

I use the subscriberContext() method to set the value like:

```
someFlux().subscriberContext(Context.of(MDC_ATTRIBUTE, MDC.get(MDC_ATTRIBUTE)));
```

I also can access the context in the chain. For example with a flatMap:

```
.flatMap(r -> Mono.subscriberContext().map(ctx -> {
    String name = ctx.getOrDefault(MDC_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, "NO CTX");
    return r;
}))
```

Also `doOnEach()` works:

```
.doOnEach(signal -> {
    Context ctx = signal.getContext();
    if (signal.isOnNext()) {
        try (MDC.MDCCloseable closeable = MDC.putCloseable(MDC_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ctx.getOrDefault(MDC_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, "MAAAAN"))) {
            log.debug("FINISHED: {}", requestName);
        }
    }
})
```

There is just one problem with it. I want to log something in `doOnSubscribe`, `doOnError` and in `doOnSuccess`. While I could use doOnEach to check for `signal.isOnNext()` or `signal.isOnComplete()`, I found out that `signal.isOnSubscribe()` is never called.

So **the question is**: How can I get the context in `doOnSubscribe()` or is this simply not possible?

Comment: Do you want to get the subscription event raised even if the `Flux` is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, not in 100% use cases and with a bit of a trick:

```
Flux.just("foo")
    .doOnSubscribe(sub -> {
        Scannable actual = Scannable.from(sub).scan(Scannable.Attr.ACTUAL);
        if (actual instanceof CoreSubscriber) {
            Context context = ((CoreSubscriber) actual).currentContext();

            System.out.println(context);
        }
    })
    .map(v -> "value: " + v) //below or above doOnSubscribe is fine
    .subscriberContext(Context.of("foo", "bar")) //MUST be below doOnSubscribe
    .blockLast();
```

Comment: What about doOnCancel()? Is it possible to access it in that case?

Comment: no. especially since ties to the actual downstream subscriber that hold the context have probably been already severed when the cancel signal reaches your doOnCancel

Comment: so currently it is not possible. and it is not feasible, either? would it be worth creating a feature request for that?

Comment: this is a result of the whole *architecture* of reactor (and of the Context feature), so this is unlikely to change for cancel